# Angular :leave :enter behaving irregularly on ngFor after sorting

Tags: angular, animation, ngfor

While trying out some things with the angular animation library I experience a weird issue. When i use an `ngFor` directive to display some list items and animate them with `:enter` and `:leave` animations the wrong animation is used when the list is sorted before an element is removed. The `:enter` animation is displayed instead of the `:leave` animation.

```
animations: [
  trigger('items', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ transform: 'translate3d(0, 50px, 0)', opacity: 0 }),  
      animate('500ms ease', 
        style({ transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)', opacity: 1 }))  
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({ width: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)', opacity: 1 }),  
      animate('500ms ease', 
        style({ transform: 'translate3d(0, -50px, 0)', opacity: 0 }))  
    ]),
  ])
]
```

Those are the animations in my components declaration.

```
<h1 @items *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" (click)="remove(i)">{{item}}</h1>
```

This is my components html.

But when i put my `:leave` animation before my `:enter` animation everything is working as expected. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

An example on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l61zfr

Comment: I don't see the bug. Is there a precise sequence of actions that we should follow?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes you should press the reorder button and then click on the numbers to remove them. Then you will see that the wrong animation is triggered. When you test is without reordering you see the right animation.

Comment: The behavior appears to be browser-dependent. As far as I can see, the bug is present in Firefox. One correction: make sure to include the parentheses in the sort expression: `(a, b) => (a - b) * multiplicator`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Okay interesting. I also experience the bug on Chromium Version 75.0.3770.90.